# Method name as POST parameter in Laravel API

Tags: php, rest, laravel-routing, laravel-5

I want to make Laravel RESTful API and also i have something that can send request to www but there is problem - this THING can send only GET and POST. Is there way to configure Laravel to know that i sent method name as a parameter for ex. in _method parameter and redirect to proper Route (i prefer making Route::resource so that's why i'm asking)?

Comment: Could possibly use rewrite to get data out of the POST/GET and modify the url

Comment: Doesn't sending `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">` for example work for [Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) anymore?

Comment: But guys im not using PHP as sender but some program that can send only GET or POST

Comment: @PawełMiczka doesn't matter where it comes from you can use the web server rewrite (apache or nginx whatever is running on your server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called **Method Tunneling through POST**.

In many scenarios clients are limited to the HTTP GET and POST methods only. In order to help work-around this limitation, RESTful servers can support method tunneling through POST. The methods that can be executed through tunneling are MERGE, PUT and DELETE.

To issue a request with method tunneling a client sets up a request with body and headers as needed, but uses POST as the HTTP method instead of the actual required one. It then adds one more header, "X-HTTP-Method", and gives it the value MERGE, PUT or DELETE.

Servers must check if POST requests have the X-HTTP-Method header set to one of the valid values and if so execute the rest of the request as if the header value was the actual HTTP method for it.